# scrape data- attribute using goutte?

Tags: javascript, php, html, web-scraping, goutte

How to scrape the `data-` attribute from a `<a>` link using [goutte](https://github.com/FriendsOfPHP/Goutte) and [laravel](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/)?

I want to scrape a tag like so:

```
<a class="ProfileNav-stat ProfileNav-stat--link u-borderUserColor u-textCenter js-tooltip js-nav u-textUserColor" data-nav="following" href="/rogerhamilton/following" data-original-title="987,358 Following">
```

within this `<a>` link I want to then scrape the `data-original-title` tag.

My code is:

```
$client = new Client();

//  Hackery to allow HTTPS
$guzzleclient = new \GuzzleHttp\Client([
    'timeout' => 60,
    'verify' => false,
]);

//  Hackery to allow HTTPS
$client->setClient($guzzleclient);
$crawler = $client->request('GET', 'url');


$elements = $crawler->filter('.ProfileNav-stat.ProfileNav-stat--link')->each(function($node){
    $x = $node->filter('data-original-title');
    dd($x);
});
```

but it doesn't return the correct data.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For anyone else that comes accross this issue. Its as simple as filtering down to the link and then doing something like `$node->filter('.classname or #ID')->attr('data-original-title')`.